# Can't install phpmyadmin to AlmaLinux 8.7 via Putty (Can't find phpmyadmin, when installing)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, yum

I am trying to get phpmyadmin installed with yum. I am a beginner regarding this and I have sofar managed to install the EPEL repo and also remi. But when I try to execute yum install phpMyAdmin it tells me it can't be found. I am thankful for any response!

I have tried many different things including what is shown in the picture, but also here it tells me that the php72w-fpm and php72w-opcache cannot be found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnM4J.png)

Answer (score 0):

php72w package are from webtatic which is a dead project for 3 years and does not provide anything for  EL-8 or EL-9

For a proper configuration / usage of "remi" repository, follow the [wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

phpMyAdmin is in "remi" repository, which is not enabled by default as it replace some base packages.

So, once PHP is installed

```
dnf --enablerepo=remi install phpMyAdmin
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! However now when I try to start the mysql I get this error: sudo service mysql start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysql.service
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.

Comment: My answer was about PHP, MySQL is another question (and sorry not enough info to help on this, at least, check the logs)